# I bought a New Computer and it doesn't have a Wi-Fi Adapter

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, wifi-driver

I bought a refurbished windows 10 HP from newegg. When I booted up for the first time it only gave me the option to connect to the internet via ethernet. After some investigation, I looked at the device manager, specifically the network adapters, and I do not see a wifi adapter. I see:

- Network adapters

  - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection
  - WAN miniport (IKEv2)
  - ...
  - WAN Miniport (SSTP)

I need Wi-Fi. How can I fix?

Comment: Buy a WiFi adapter?

Comment: ok... how? I know nothing about hardware. Can I download one? This is the last thing in the world I want to deal with.

Comment: @fishrec - You cannot download a WiFI adapter.  You will have to install one yourself.  This isn't something we can help you do, since it requires, physical access to your machine.  This is only something you can resolve.

Comment: Is it definitely the case that I am missing a Wi-Fi adapter given the information provided?

Comment: This is an HP Desktop computer, correct?  So the odds are it did not come with Wi-Fi . None of my desktop computers came with Wi-Fi but I added that to my current desktop computer.  If Laptop, return it to the seller.

Comment: Well, you said it doesn't have one, so we've assumed that's the case. Are there any devices with question marks or other problems in _Device Manager_? If not, you have to buy the adapter. It's a piece of hardware, you can't download it. USB adapters exist.

Comment: Model of HP????

Comment: Thank you all. I purchased a Wi-Fi USB adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments on the question mentioned, your computer almost certainly does not have a wifi adapter. You need to purchase one to be able to access the internet.

Go to your favorite online retailer and search for "USB Wifi Adapter" - here is a link to that search on [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb%20wifi%20adapter) (no affiliation). TP-Link, Netgear, and Linksys are some trustworthy brands. You don't need anything fancy - something that costs about $20 will work perfectly. If you need a particular recommendation then [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08D72GSMS) should be perfect.

Compatibility-wise, if your computer is running Windows 10 then the only thing you should need to do once you have the adapter is to plug it in to a USB port - just like a keyboard or mouse. After that, you just need to connect to your wifi network the same way you would on any other PC.